# Indexed family of sets defined by a half-open interval

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose $A = \{A_n : n \in\mathbb N\}$ is an indexed family of
sets with N as the index set, where $A_n$ is the half-open interval $\left[\frac1n, 2 − \frac1n\right)$
for each $n \in\mathbb N$.

(a) Write $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$.

(b) Find the intersection of $A_n$

(c) Find the union of $A_n$

I'm attempting to understand this, but the half-open interval is throwing me off.  For (a) I have $A_1$ = $\{1\}$, $A_2$ = $\left[\frac12, \frac32\right]$and $A_3$ = $\left[\frac13, \frac53\right]$ and I believe the answer to (b) and (c) on a closed interval would be $[1]$ and $(0, 2)$ respectively, but it's the first week of class and the text only offers a paragraph on the matter.  Does the interval being half-open have any effect on $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$, and how does it change the intersection and union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the intervals are half open does affect the result. Your answers for $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ are not correct.
The fact that the interval in open at right means that the right endpoint does not belong to the set.  For instance $A_1=\emptyset$ since by tge very definition $A_n=\{x\in \mathbb{R} | \frac{1}{n} \leq x < 2-\frac{1}{n}\}$ and of course there are no points which are both greater or equal than $1$ and strictly smaller than $1$. You must correct $A_2$ and $A_3$ also.

Comment: I understand now.  That was the paradox I was hung up on.  If the interval is open on the right, how can 1 be included by the left endpoint and excluded by the right.  I wrongly assumed maybe it would still be just 1, but it seems obvious now that it would in fact be the empty set.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

obviously $$A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset...$$therefore $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=A_1$$For finding the union first note that any $\epsilon>0$ belongs to set $\{A_N,A_{N+1},A_{N+2},...\}$ where $N>\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$. With the same argument for sufficiently small positive $\epsilon$, $2-\epsilon$ belongs to $\{A_N,A_{N+1},A_{N+2},...\}$ for some $N$. This is clear that $\{0,2\}$ doesn't belong to any $A_n$, therefore $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=(0,2)$$

Comment: This part I understood and your conclusion matches my own.  To clarify what I am asking, are the answers to (a), (b), and (c) different than if it were simply a closed interval?  If so, how?

Comment: Well! You can write $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ easily, and the answer to part b changes accordingly but the answer to part c is still persistent. Now take for example $A_n=(-\dfrac{1}{n},2-\dfrac{1}{n})$. Therefore $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=[0,2)$$ how can you show that? Also can you find the union?